# Disagreement between Integration over Region and Contour integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, regions

I am trying to do a line integral along an ellipse. The am integrating the field $x^2 + y^2$. I want to integrate over an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ where the perimeter of the ellipse is $2\pi$ and $a = 1.5$. To get $b$ such that the perimeter is $2\pi$, I use Ramanujans equation. Here is the code I use to do this integral over a region:

```
a = 1.5;
b =  1/3 (3 - 2 a + Sqrt[3 + 6 a - 5 a^2]);
R = ImplicitRegion[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1., {x, y}];
NIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] R]
```

This integral returns 5.397.

I can also parameterize the ellipse using $x = a\cos{\theta}$ and $y = b\cos{\theta}$. Then I would plug this into the field and integrate over $\theta$:

```
a = 1.5;
b =  1/3 (3 - 2 a + Sqrt[3 + 6 a - 5 a^2]);
NIntegrate[(a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (b*Sin[\[Theta]])^2,{\[Theta],0,2*Pi}]
```

This integral gives me 7.33. Why are the two integrals returning different results?

Comment: By the way, in this case you could integrate directly over the (boundary of) ellipse: `Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}]]`, and with exact `a` and `b`, get an exact answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to add Jacobian in curve integral. `Sqrt[D[a*Cos[θ], θ]^2 +D[b*Sin[θ], θ]^2]` when we change the variables in integral.

```
a = 1.5;
b = 1/3 (3 - 2 a + Sqrt[3 + 6 a - 5 a^2]);
NIntegrate[((a*Cos[θ])^2 + (b*Sin[θ])^2)*Sqrt[
  D[a*Cos[θ], θ]^2 + 
   D[b*Sin[θ], θ]^2], {θ, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

> `5.39697`

Comment: OP, see [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition).